# Highlight menu parent

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying highlight the MENU ITEM when I have the SUBMENU selected.
I can see the code below is working to keep the menu item selected when I don't have a submenu. When I have a menu with submenu, the submenu is the only one that stays selected/highlight but menu.

I was trying different approach without success, can you help me? Thank you.

HTML:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Item 1.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 1.2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Item 2.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 2.2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 6</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Item 6.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 6.2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
  ul#menu, ul#menu ul.sub-menu {
        padding:0;
        margin: 0;
    }

    #menu {
        float: left;
        list-style: none outside none;
        padding-left: 20px;
        margin-top: 5px;

    }
    #menu li {
        border-right: 1px solid #7A0019;
        float: left;
        padding: 2px;
        font-size: 15px;
        position: relative;
    }
    #menu li a {
        color: #FFFFFF;
        display: block;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    #menu li a:hover {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #CCC;
        color: #000000;
        text-shadow: 0 0 5px #FFFFFF;
        z-index: 100;
    }

    #menu li a:active {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #CCC;
        color: #000000;
        text-shadow: 0 0 5px #FFFFFF;
        z-index: 100;
    }



    #menu li ul {
        background-color: #7A0019;
        display: none;
        left: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 29px;
        z-index: 100;
    }

    #menu li:hover ul, #menu li.over ul {
        display: block;
    }

    #menu li ul li {
        border: 1px solid #7A0019;
        display: block;
        width: 130px;
        z-index: 50;

        -webkit-transition-delay:0.1s;     
        -moz-transition-delay:0.1s; 
        -ms-transition-delay:0.1s;     
        -o-transition-delay:0.1s;     
        transition-delay:0.1s;         
    }

.active_menu {      color: #000000 !important;
                    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #FFFFFF;
                    z-index: 100;
                    background-color: #FFCC33;
                    cursor:pointer !important;}
```

Jquery:

```
$(function(){     
    var url = window.location.href; 
    $("#menu a").each(function() {
        if(url == (this.href)) { 
            $(this).closest("li").addClass("active_menu");
            $(this).closest("li a").css("color","#000");
        }
    });
});
```

**Solution:**

After so many tries finally a simple way to reach the result.
Thank you ALL.

```
($(function () {
    var url = window.location.href;
    $("#menu a").each(function () {
        if (url == (this.href)) {
            $(this).closest(".menuHeader").children("a").addClass("active_menu");
            $(this).closest("li").addClass("active_menu");
            $(this).closest("li a").css("color", "#000");
        }
    });
});
```

Thank you Jesse, JEES and Gregg.

Comment: please check my updated answer, hopefully this is what you are trying to get

Comment: I'm sorry that it is not what you want, still, by any chance, is what you need is to match the webpage URL and if matches the value of let's say menu or submenu item's url in the `href` part then trigger that element as selected?

Comment: Jess, I need to highlight the menu and submenu and if I select a submenu the menu and submenu will be always selected.

Comment: it is JEES not Jesse :), check it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, this way may work for you. Add class to the parent li, and then add/remove class to the parent li on hover/mouse out.

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b56vy1w5/

**HTML**

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li class="menuHeader"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="menuHeader"><a href="#">Item 1</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Item 1.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 1.2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li  class="menuHeader"><a href="#">Item 2</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Item 2.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 2.2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 6</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Item 6.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 6.2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(function(){     
    var url = window.location.href;
    $(".sub-menu li a").hover(function() {
        console.log($(this));
        $(this).closest(".menuHeader").children("a").addClass("active_menu");
    });

    $(".sub-menu li a").mouseout(function(){
        $(this).closest(".menuHeader").children("a").removeClass("active_menu");
    })
});
```

Comment: Hello Jesse, thank you for you take time to help me. I would like to know if I can keep the parent menu selected, is this possible?

Comment: what do you mean, keep it selected? it stays highlighted when you hover over the sub-menu

Comment: Hi Jesse, I would like to say thank you. After use your idea I just did a small adaptation in my code.

Comment: I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's hope I figured it out this time, and my name is JEES and not Jesse :P..
however as this example can't be done on jsfiddle or on S.O.. here's a link showing it in action http://test.mi-creativity.com/highlight-parent/

So we basically check if it is a sub-item or not depending on if it's closest `ul` has class `sub-menu` or not, and add style upon that, here is the code

**JS: *external.js***

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var url = window.location.href,
    websitename = "http://localhost/test/highlight-parent/";

    $("#menu a").each(function () {
        var href = $(this).attr("href");
        if( websitename == url){ 
            $("#homepage").addClass("active_menu");
            $("#homepage a").css("color","#000");
        }else if( websitename + href == url){
            if($(this).closest("ul").hasClass("sub-menu")){
                $(this).closest("#menu > li").addClass("active_menu");
            }else{       
                $(this).parent().addClass("active_menu");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li id="homepage"><a href="index.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Item 1</a>

        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="subitem_1.1.html">Item 1.1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="subitem_1.1.html">Item 1.2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Item 2</a>

        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="subitem_2.1.html">Item 2.1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="subitem_2.2.html">Item 2.2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="item_3.html">Item 3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="item_4.html">Item 4</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="item_5.html">Item 5</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Item 6</a>

        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="subitem_6.1.html">Item 6.1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="subitem_6.2.html">Item 6.2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="external.js"></script>
```

***UPDATE:***
**Extra CSS:**

I've also added this snippet to get rid of the text-shadow that was affecting the the color of the selected menu item and make trying to set font color as black through javascript useless, also thus we can omit both `.css("color","#000");` lines in the javascript code:

```
.active_menu a{
   color:#000 !important;
   text-shadow:none;
}
```

Comment: Hi JEES, sorry for the mistake that I did about your name. I can see you put an ID in the LI Homepage and you are using websitename = "http://localhost/test/highlight-parent/"; Can I use without websitename and without the ID? Thank you.

Comment: @Low Rider, Sure you can, i put the ID into the first `#menu` element just for that when you load the homepage for the first time, instead of have NO highlighted items,  it will highlight that first item menu as initialization, it is not a must thought

Comment: and about the `websitename = "localhost/test/highlight-parent/";` I used it this way because i am using *relative* links as `href="subitem_2.2.html"`, so i added that part `else if( websitename + href == url)` to make this condition true, BUT if you want to omit the websitename part, *make sure you use STATIC URL's in your `href` *, something like `href="//website-example.com/path/item_5.html`, if you use it this way, everything will go just fine

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding what your trying to do. You want to highlight the menu item of the page the user is on, PLUS the parent menu item if that menu item is in a sub-menu. I'm seeing answers about setting classes on hover and mouseover and I didn't see anything in your question or code about hover effects. So I just wanted to make sure I understood what you were trying to do.

Something like this should do it. Instead of looping through all the anchors looking for the one with the matching url just use the selector to find it.  (untested):

```
$(function(){     
    var url = window.location.href; 
    // get the active link by looking for the anchor matching the url
    var $active = $('#menu a[href=' + url + ']');
    // get a reference to the li wrapping the anchor
    var $li = $active.closest("li");
    // add the active_menu Class to the li
    $li.addClass("active_menu");
    // set the color of the active Anchor
    // although I'd use the stylesheet: li.active_menu a { color: #000; }
    $active.css("color","#000");

    // Check the UL parent of the li for the class 'sub-menu'
    if($li.parent().hasClass('sub-menu')){
        // if it is a sub-menu find the li wrapping the sub-menu and add the active_menu class
        $li.parent().closest("li").addClass('active_menu');
    }

});
```

Comment: Gregg, you are right about my question, but your solution didn't work.

Comment: The issue is that your menu is using relative urls but window.location.href is returning the fully qualified url. I've created a fiddle where I hardcoded the 'url' variable and set a sub-menu item's href to that value and it works. http://jsfiddle.net/anpkpeqy/

Comment: If all your menu links are root relative you could change "var url = window.location.href;" to "var url = window.location.pathname;" I think that may fix it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer that just works with your HTML just replace:

```
$(this).closest("li").addClass("active_menu");
$(this).closest("li a").css("color","#000");
```

with:

```
$("#menu li").has("a[href='" + this.href + "']").addClass("active_menu");
$("#menu li").has("a[href='" + this.href + "']").css("color","#000");
```

Working example:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VvxaMg